# Sort list of mixed strings based on digits

Tags: python

How do I sort this list via the numerical values?  Is a regex required to remove the numbers or is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

```
to_sort

['12-foo',
 '1-bar',
 '2-bar',
 'foo-11',
 'bar-3',
 'foo-4',
 'foobar-5',
 '6-foo',
 '7-bar']
```

Desired output is as follows:

```
1-bar
2-bar
bar-3
foo-4
foobar-5
6-foo
7-bar
foo-11
12-foo
```

Comment: For me, the most "Pythonic" way is the clearest one. Don't always try to Python-way  everything, but focus more on readability and good practices.

Comment: @idjaw I had tried `sorted` with a `key` but the answers below have helped me understand this better.

Comment: @adele Always post your attempts, we always learn from each other's mistakes. Wrong attempts are extremely helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution is the following regex extraction:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(re.search('\d+', x).group(0)))
```

---

```
>>> l
['12-foo', '1-bar', '2-bar', 'foo-11', 'bar-3', 'foo-4', 'foobar-5', '6-foo', '7-bar']
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: int(re.search('\d+', x).group(0)))
['1-bar', '2-bar', 'bar-3', 'foo-4', 'foobar-5', '6-foo', '7-bar', 'foo-11', '12-foo']
```

The `key` is the extracted digit (converted to `int` to avoid sorting lexographically).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use regex

```
>>> l = ['12-foo', '1-bar', '2-bar', 'foo-11', 'bar-3', 'foo-4', 'foobar-5', '6-foo', '7-bar']

>>> sorted(l, key = lambda x: int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x))))

['1-bar', '2-bar', 'bar-3', 'foo-4', 'foobar-5', '6-foo', '7-bar', 'foo-11', '12-foo']
```

Comment: If the input is long, run both implementations and see which one is faster. `filter(std.isdigit, x)` creates a long (per-character) temporary list, which can be slow.

Comment: True, filter is probably even slower than a genexp for this.

Comment: I have marked up the answer as this helps my understanding and it is interesting to see how you used `isdigit`.  thanks